# Postgresql error: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE with json_object_keys

Tags: postgresql

I am getting below error in Postgresql 12 for below query:

Error: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE

case when(marks <> '{}') then json_object_keys(marks::json) else null end as mark1

how to re-write this in Postgresql 12.

Comment: `marks` should be a `jsonb` column so that the cast isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the set returning function into the FROM clause. The CASE condition can then be turned into a JOIN condition.

You have given next to none details about the structure and the desired output, so I have to guess what you are trying to achieve.

Maybe something like:

```
select ...
from the_table t
   left join json_object_keys(marks::json) as m on marks <> '{}'
```